# Segfault accessing struct member after using realloc 4 times in c

Tags: c, realloc, trie

Im getting a segfault whenever nTable->size = 4, and I cant figure out for the life of me why. I added a comment in the code where the segfault happens. The purpose is to read in a text file and create a trie (I think this is a trie?) of the words read-in, re-using letters of previous words if they share the same first few letters. This code just uses 1 word (abcde) for demonstration

```
#include <stdbool.h>//for bool
#include <stdlib.h> //for malloc
#include <string.h> //strlen, strchr
#include <ctype.h>  //tolower
#include <stdio.h>

#define CHARACTERS 27

typedef struct node
{
    struct node *nLetter[CHARACTERS];
    bool end;
    int size;
} node;

const char *cLetters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'";

node *nTable;

int main ()
{
    char *cWord = "abcde";

    nTable = malloc(sizeof(node));

    if (nTable == NULL){
        return false;
    }

    nTable->size = 1;   //initialize table to size 1
    nTable->end = false;//word not 0 letters

    node *nPath = NULL; //create the path between each letter of the word

    int iLen = 0;

    iLen = strlen(cWord);

    if(cWord[iLen - 1] == '\n') //strlen counts \n as a character, but not \0 (end of string). -1 if \n included
    {
        iLen--;
    }

//store word in table

    nPath = nTable; //reset path to beginning of table

    for (int n = 0; n < iLen; n++)
    {
        char *p = strchr(cLetters, tolower(cWord[n]));

        //Check Path
        if (nPath->nLetter[p - cLetters] == NULL)   //If path exists, move along path (in else below)
        {                                   //if no path yet, create below.
            nTable = realloc(nTable, ++nTable->size  * sizeof(node));    //increase size of nTable by 1 node
            if (nTable == NULL)
            {
                return false;   //failed to increase size of nTable
            }

            //Connect Path
            nPath->nLetter[p - cLetters] = nTable + (nTable->size - 1) * sizeof(node);    //create path from previous letter to next
            nPath = nPath->nLetter[p - cLetters];         //update nPath pointee to newest letter

            if (n + 1 == iLen)  //last letter of word
            {
                nPath->end = true;
            }
            else    //not last letter of word
            {
                nPath->end = false;   //SEGFAULT HERE when nTable->size is 4 or more
            }
        } //end if new path (if)
        else    //path exists, move along path
        {
            nPath = nPath->nLetter[p - cLetters];
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: `nPath->nLetter[p - cLetters] = nTable + (nTable->size - 1) * sizeof(node)` looks wrong. The RHS is doing pointer arithmetic so should not multiply by `sizeof(node)`. That is, should be just `nTable + (nTable->size - 1)`.

Comment: `nLetter` is not initialized and used as `if (nPath->nLetter[p - cLetters] == NULL)`

Comment: Not relevant to the root problem, but `return false` and `return true` from the `main` function doesn't do what you've intended. The value that the `main` function returns should be one of the `0`, `EXIT_SUCCESS`, and `EXIT_FAILURE`. `return EXIT_SUCCESS` is equivalent to `return 0` (when returning from the `main` function).

Comment: @mch , that line is just checking if its initialized or not. If its not initialized, that condition will return true, and the code below will allocate more memory in order to initialize it. Correct me if Im wrong, but that was my intention

Comment: @kaylum , please have a look at my comment below the 1st answer

Comment: @TravelKidKurty no, the check is if it is `NULL`, not uninitialized, you cannot test for uninitialized. You have to initialize them to `NULL` and test for `NULL`. In your case it can be true, but do not have to, it's simply undefined.

Comment: @TravelKidKurty two pple are telling you the same thing. Look up "pointer arithmetic". And for the uninitialised issue. You can't check for uninitialised memory. Uninitialised does not mean it is set to NULL. More likely contains random garbage values

Comment: @mch I implemented both of your suggestions, and its worked! Clearly I was wrong for both, but thats part of the learning! :) Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: @kaylum Ill have a read on that pointer arithmetic- Im glad it is indeed your way and not mine, much easier on the eyes and code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problematic line is this one:

```
nPath->nLetter[p - cLetters] = nTable + (nTable->size - 1) * sizeof(node);    //create path from previous letter to next
```

when you do pointer arithmetic, you shouldn't multiply by the size of the type.
Instead, the line should be:

```
nPath->nLetter[p - cLetters] = nTable + nTable->size - 1;
```

Comment: Are you sure? (you could be right, Im just walking through my thinking) If I did something like `nTable = realloc(nTable, 2 * sizeof(node));`, it would allocate enough memory to store 2 nodes within. nTable would point to the first node, and youre saying for me to point to the 2nd node, I would use `nTable + nTable->size - 1`, where nTable->size == 2?

Comment: I'm sure.

When you increment/decrement a pointer (e.g. "p++") , the address is calculated by the compiler based on the size of the underlying type. 

malloc/realloc, on the other hand, are not aware of the type and therefore require that you pass the size in bytes.